# Android TableLayout control with uniform row/column sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I'm creating an application in Android, for which I need to divide the screen into uniform rows and columns to fill the whole screen.

I know how to do this in HTML and WPF (and standard GDI+), but I can't find a suitable control in Android.

I'm limited to Android 3.2, so I can't use the GridLayout, which looks like it could do what I want.

Once I have this 'table/grid' control, I want be be able to put Buttons, TextViews etc.. into the cells, and indicate whether they span multiple columns or rows.

I've been experimenting with the TableLayout control, but I can't seem to get the columns/rows to be of a uniform size.

I'm also building this grid on the fly at runtime.

Is there any such control which will allow this?

Thanks,
Rich.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have acheived this by creating a new class deriving from ViewGroup which lays out my 'Views' in the correct fashion. This works well, although I'm having some trouble aligning text within the child Views.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the column widths, you can set a weight on each view in a row:

```
    <TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
```

This may also work if you put a weight on the  as well, but I've never tested that.

Comment: I've already been trying with the TableLayout, but you don't seem to be able to span rows or columns.. I think I'm going to write my own custom control.